# @WebParam java rest service

Tags: java, rest

I implemented the following rest service ...

```
@PUT
@Path("/scanner2Test")
@WebMethod(operationName = "scanner2Test")
@WebResult(name = TestKey)
public TestKey scanner2Test(@WebParam(name = "user") String user, @WebParam(name = "mail") String mail, @WebParam(name = "subject") String subject)
```

If i try to read out the parameters but only the first one contains a value. all others are empty. I tried it with different browser rest plug-ins but the result is the same. I tried to set the values in the request header, in the body, but always with the same result. what's going wrong here? why do i get only one value?

Comment: Did you verify that all "name" parameters in the `@WebParam` annotation are coming to you as parameters in the header?

Comment: @Thomas Which REST implementation are you using and could you show details of how you are calling the service?